# Why can't I change the label under my UpdateProgress div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updateprogress

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="PreLoader" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="divWaiting">
            <asp:Image ID="preload" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/preloader.gif" />&nbsp
            <asp:Label ID="pmtProc1" runat="server" Text="Payment Processing ... Please Wait" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I can't seem to access `pmtProc1` in my code-behind, why?

Comment: Any server-side control within a template (as used by things like repeaters, gridviews and updateprogress) are not directly contained by the page.  You need to do a FindControl on the specific template within the server-control it lives in, in this case within `PreLoader`

Comment: that was my next attempt. I think I have it working now using JavaScript. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Paul, can you please let me know how you solved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any server-side control within a template (as used by things like `<asp:Repeater>`, `<asp:GridView>` and `<asp:UpdateProgress>` for example) are not directly contained by the page.

In this case you need to do a `.FindControl` on the `<asp:UpdateProgress>` control itself...

For instance...

```
Label pmtProc1 = (Label)PreLoader.FindControl("pmtProc1");
pmtProc1.Text = "New Text";
```

**Note**, this won't work with controls where multiple templates can occur (such as `<asp:Repeater>` and `<asp:GridView` for example)... in this situation you need to find the `item` in question and then find the control within that item.

For instance...

```
Label lbl = (Label)myRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("myLabel");
```